# How can I re offer an item in a LinkedBlockingQueue at the first place?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a function that use the `((LinkedBlockingQueue)queue).take()` method to get the next request to handle.

If something goes wrong during the request handling, I'd like to re offer the request in my queue but in the very first place to ensure the requests are actually handled in the arrival order

Note: at this point I know that if it failed it was because a service was down and that the request will be properly handled in few minutes.

How can I achieve that ? `LinkedBlockingQueue` can only offer an item to the tail, not to the head. I need something like `queue.untake(item)`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `LinkedBlockingDequeue`, you can use `offerFirst` and `offerLast` to maintain the arrival order.

Answer (score 1):

You need `LinkedBlockingDeque` instead. Use the `offerFirst` method.

Note that if you've got multiple threads polling the queue, you can't actually be sure that it'll be reprocessed before anything else.